# How do i get this fancy M in latex?

Tags: math-mode, symbols

How do I get this symbol in latex. (I am using overleaf currently)
Couldn't find it any web-resources.

[image: PatchCore memory bank]

Comment: `\mathcal{M}` ?

Comment: @Thruston : Thanks